# Is it possible to change the default file format in MeshLab from ply to stl?

Tags: meshlab

Whenever I repair then save a model in MeshLab, it wants to save it in ply format. I ALWAYS want to save it as stl and it is tiresome to have to constantly change the format. Anyway of setting to default to stl?

I haven't figured out how to try anything. I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a filename ended in `.stl`, you don't need to change the `Files of type` option.